# SQL Bigquery convert timestamp into interval of 5 mints

Tags: database, google-bigquery

In Google bigquery database,
Convert minute level timestamp to an interval of 5 minutes.
The 5 minutes interval is standard time interval .
Below is just an example how i want the data to be presented

`test                    hd_count
2013-12-20 10:40:30          1 
2013-12-20 10:41:30          3
2013-12-20 10:42:30          2
2013-12-20 10:43:30          1 
2013-12-20 10:44:30          1`

I want this to be represented as

`test_1                   test_2                 hd_count
 2013-12-20 10:40:30        2013-12-20 10:44:30     8`

I have looked into similar request in other answer but none of them seem to work for big query.Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH minmax AS (
  SELECT MIN(test) AS mintest, MAX(test) AS maxtest, 5 AS step
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
), intervals AS (
  SELECT 
    TIMESTAMP_ADD(mintest, INTERVAL step * num MINUTE) AS test1,
    TIMESTAMP_ADD(mintest, INTERVAL step * 60* (1 + num) - 1 SECOND) AS test2
  FROM minmax, 
  UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0,  DIV(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(maxtest, mintest, MINUTE) , step))) AS num
)
SELECT test1, test2, SUM(hd_count) AS hd_count
FROM intervals JOIN `project.dataset.table`
ON test BETWEEN test1 AND test2
GROUP BY test1, test2
```

you can test / play with above using dummy data as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2013-12-20 10:40:30' test, 1 hd_count UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2013-12-20 10:41:30', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2013-12-20 10:42:30', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2013-12-20 10:43:30', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2013-12-20 10:44:30', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2013-12-20 10:45:30', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2013-12-20 10:46:30', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2013-12-20 10:47:30', 1  
), minmax AS (
  SELECT MIN(test) AS mintest, MAX(test) AS maxtest, 5 AS step
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
), intervals AS (
  SELECT 
    TIMESTAMP_ADD(mintest, INTERVAL step * num MINUTE) AS test1,
    TIMESTAMP_ADD(mintest, INTERVAL step * 60* (1 + num) - 1 SECOND) AS test2
  FROM minmax, 
  UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0,  DIV(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(maxtest, mintest, MINUTE) , step))) AS num
)
SELECT test1, test2, SUM(hd_count) AS hd_count
FROM intervals JOIN `project.dataset.table`
ON test BETWEEN test1 AND test2
GROUP BY test1, test2
ORDER BY test1
```

output is as below

```sql
test1                       test2                       hd_count     
2013-12-20 10:40:30 UTC     2013-12-20 10:45:29 UTC     8    
2013-12-20 10:45:30 UTC     2013-12-20 10:50:29 UTC     6
```

Comment: It seems like based on this and past questions that GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY would be useful. You could consider [filing a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187149%2B) if you think so too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a standard SQL UDF-based approach that enables arbitrary alignments up to millisecond precision.  I use it when I'm working with more granular time intervals:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION bracketTimestampByMillis(ts TIMESTAMP, bracketMillis INT64) RETURNS TIMESTAMP AS (
  TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(CAST(FLOOR(
       (UNIX_MILLIS(ts) -  UNIX_MILLIS(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(ts, DAY))) / bracketMillis) AS INT64) 
  * bracketMillis + UNIX_MILLIS(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(ts, DAY))));
```

To demonstrate, here's another UDF which consumes the first to build an array of timestamps aligned to various intervals:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION emitTimeBrackets(ts TIMESTAMP) RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<bracket STRING, tsVal TIMESTAMP>> AS (
    [STRUCT("exact" as bracket, ts as tsVal),
     STRUCT("minute", bracketTimestampByMillis(ts, 60 * 1000)),
     STRUCT("5 minute", bracketTimestampByMillis(ts, 5 * 60 * 1000)),
     STRUCT("15 minute", bracketTimestampByMillis(ts, 15 * 60 * 1000)),
     STRUCT("hour", bracketTimestampByMillis(ts, 60 * 60 * 1000)),
     STRUCT("quarter day", bracketTimestampByMillis(ts, 6 * 3600 * 1000))
    ]
);

SELECT emitTimeBrackets(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) as b
```